# Count number of pairs, triplets, etc in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

If I have a list like below in a google spreadsheet, how could I count how many pairs, triplets, etc are in the list? The pair count would only count pairs and not triplets or higher groups.

```
apple
orange
pear
orange
apple
pear
orange
```

Result would give 2 for pair count and 1 for triplet count.

I would like to accomplish this with a formula in a single cell without using other cells for intermediate steps. Here is a link to a sheet showing the end result I want but using intermediate steps, which are unwanted.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yVFYH226cebOu-adt-e_2VQnULdxWZKOWOnB4fK2OCc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you should use `countif` to find times of appearance for each element.

Comment: I would like to do this inside of a single cell without any other cells being used for intermediate steps. Going to update main post clarifying better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pair count-

```
=COUNTIFS(QUERY(QUERY(A1:A7,"select A, count(A) group by A label count(A) ''"),"select Col2"),"2")& " Pairs"
```

For triple count-

```
=COUNTIFS(QUERY(QUERY(A1:A7,"select A, count(A) group by A label count(A) ''"),"select Col2"),"3")& " Triple"
```

Alternative formula-

```
=COUNTIFS(CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(HSTACK(A1:A7,INDEX(COUNTIFS(A1:A7,A1:A7)))),2),"2") & " Pairs"
=COUNTIFS(CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(HSTACK(A1:A7,INDEX(COUNTIFS(A1:A7,A1:A7)))),2),"3") & " Triples"
```

[image]

Comment: So, would that need to be done for every number? What if we don't know beforehand how many duplicates will be there, like 23.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier Problem is trailing words like `pairs, triples.....` Otherwise you can count them by a single formula. But you can't put those words in a single formula.

Comment: Give a try to- `=QUERY(QUERY(A1:A7,"select A, count(A) group by A label count(A) ''"),
"select Col2, count(Col2) group by Col2 label Col2 'Count', count(Col2) 'Pair Count'")`.

Comment: Thanks @Harun24hr, I've only tried the first solution but that suits my needs. All I had to do was figure out that if my dataset is in column D instead all instances of A need to be replaced with D.

Comment: I found an "issue" with the first solution given in this post being that it is case sensitive, granted I did not give being non case sensitive as a requirement and it's an easy fix which uses lower() with an example below.

`=COUNTIFS(QUERY(QUERY(A1:A,"select lower(A), count(A) group by lower(A) label count(A) ''"),"select Col2"),"2")& " Pairs"`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more compact answer that gives the replicate counts in a single formula, and can in principle be scaled up to any number of replicates:

```
=arrayformula(countif(countif(A1:A,A1:A),{2;3})/{2;3}&" "&{"pair(s)";"triplet(s)"})
```

The inner COUNTIF counts the number of occurrences of each item in the list; as the list contains replicates the item counts are also replicated. The outer COUNTIF 'counts the counts', i.e. 'how many items had count 2?, how many 3?, etc.' By definition these must be multiples of the replication factor, e.g. there are 2n pairs, 3n triplicates. So the outer COUNTIF result is divided by 2 or 3 to give the number of pairs or triplicates, and then there is some array string manipulation to add the appropriate text after the number. You could scale to any arbitrary replication level just by expanding the array literals. E.g. to include quadruplicates:

```
=arrayformula(countif(countif(A1:A,A1:A),{2;3;4})/{2;3;4}&" "&{"pair(s)";"triplet(s)";"quadruplicate(s)"})
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing another method of doing this. This method helped me figure out the other solution as posted is case sensitive, I want a case insensitive solution. Is there a way to edit this formula so it only gives the number of pairs with one formula in one cell and triplets with another formula in a different cell? I want the valves in different cells that aren't auto generated like this formula does.